# Query remote hive metastore to get list of tables

Tags: hive, hql, dbvisualizer, metastore

> Hi Gurus,
>
> I want to access remote hive metastore on mapr :
> Below are the conf parameters:
>
> driver :"org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"
>
> database url : jdbc:hive2://Company.com:port number/
>
> I am using hiveserver2 and dbvisualizer is the tool from where i fire
> queries .
> I want to access this remote hive metastore and be able to
> get date of creation of tables which are more than N days old . Please
> tell me how it can be done and the hive query for the same. I have a
> jdbc code which does the same ,but i would like to know if i can
> directly write a hive query to do the same.Does hcatalog provide a way
> to do this and if so how ?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned using jdbc code to obtain your specific query results. That is the correct way.  Hive supports the following syntaxes, which are relatively simple/limited versus full fledged sql that you can do via jdbc:

- show table extended like 'regex'

It is not possible to run a full fledged query with filtering and ordering as you had done in jdbc.